# Looping this time response game under rounds function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

```
import random




print("Welcome to Response Time Tester!")
print("You will be asked to press Enter after 
random amounts of time.")
print("How close can you get? ")  
while True:
    try:
        rounds = int(input("Enter desired number 
of rounds: "))
if rounds <= 0:
        print("Number of rounds must be greater 
than zero. Try again.")
    else:
        break
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input. Enter a number.")

num = random.randint(2, 8)    

for rounds in range(1, rounds+1):
    print(f"Round {rounds} of {rounds}.")

    import time

import time
from typing import List

def calculate_rating(diff: float) -> str:
    if diff <= 0.25:
        return "Excellent!"
    elif diff <= 0.5:
        return "Great"
    elif diff <= 1:
        return "Good!"
    elif diff <= 2:
        return "OK!"
    else:
        return "Miss"

# randomly select target number of seconds between 
2 and 8 (inclusive)
target_seconds = random.randint(2, 8)
print(f"Press Enter in {target_seconds} seconds.")

# wait for 3 seconds before starting the timer
for i in range(3, 0, -1):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

print("Go!")

# record the start time
start_time = time.time()

# wait for the user to press Enter
input()

# calculate the response time and the difference 
from the target time
response_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
diff = abs(target_seconds - response_time)

# calculate the rating based on the difference and 
print it
rating = calculate_rating(diff)
print(f"Response time: {response_time} seconds.")
print(f"Target was {target_seconds} seconds, and 
your difference was {diff} seconds.")
print(f"Your rating is {rating}.")
```

This is how i want my code to run

Welcome to Response Time Tester!
You will be asked to press Enter after random amounts of time.
How close can you get?

Enter desired number of rounds: 2
Round 1 of 2
Press enter in 3 seconds
3
2
1
Go!

Response time: 3.72 seconds.
Target was 3 seconds, and your difference was 0.720000000000002 seconds
Your rating is Good!

Round 2 of 2
etc .....

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Comment: Well its hard to explain but i basically want my code to run under the loop rounds. So the user tells the program how many rounds they want to play and the game runs 2 times

Comment: So, you're explaining expected behaviour. What is the current behaviour?

Comment: So basically when you run my code it'll ask you how many rounds you want to play, when i input the amount of rounds i want to play, lets say to itll print "Round 1 of 1", "Round 2 of 2" and then itll run the actual program. I want so that under every round you will be asked to play the Response time game i have under it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your game logic into the function `game` and run it in the loop:

```
import time
import random


def calculate_rating(diff: float) -> str:
    if diff <= 0.25:
        return "Excellent!"
    elif diff <= 0.5:
        return "Great"
    elif diff <= 1:
        return "Good!"
    elif diff <= 2:
        return "OK!"
    else:
        return "Miss"


def game():
    # randomly select target number of seconds between 2 and 8 (inclusive)
    target_seconds = random.randint(2, 8)
    print(f"Press Enter in {target_seconds} seconds.")

    # wait for 3 seconds before starting the timer
    for i in range(3, 0, -1):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

    print("Go!")

    # record the start time
    start_time = time.time()

    # wait for the user to press Enter
    input()

    # calculate the response time and the difference from the target time
    response_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
    diff = abs(target_seconds - response_time)

    # calculate the rating based on the difference and print it
    rating = calculate_rating(diff)
    print(f"Response time: {response_time} seconds.")
    print(f"Target was {target_seconds} seconds, and your difference was {diff} seconds.")
    print(f"Your rating is {rating}.")


print("Welcome to Response Time Tester!")
print("You will be asked to press Enter after random amounts of time.")
print("How close can you get? ")
while True:
    try:
        rounds = int(input("Enter desired number of rounds: "))
        if rounds <= 0:
            print("Number of rounds must be greater than zero. Try again.")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Enter a number.")

for rounds in range(1, rounds + 1):
    print(f"Round {rounds} of {rounds}.")
    game()
```